# What does the number mean in 'ls(1)', 'stat(3)' and 'apt(8)'?

Tags: man

While browsing through the web and local documents, I often see expressions like this:

```
See apt(8) for more information about the available commands.
```

My question is, what does the number here stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "man man":

MANUAL SECTIONS
    The standard sections of the manual include:

```
1      User Commands
2      System Calls
3      C Library Functions
4      Devices and Special Files
5      File Formats and Conventions
6      Games et. al.
7      Miscellanea
8      System Administration tools and Daemons

Distributions customize the manual section to their specifics,
which often include additional sections.
```